# Why do overloads of 'operator<<' exist for the 'char' partial-specializations of std::basic_ostream?

Tags: c++, integer, char, operator-overloading, ostream

I would like to know *why* the following `operator<<` overloads exist for `basic_ostream`'s `char` partial-specializations:

```
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,
                                        char ch );
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,
                                        signed char ch );
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,
                                        unsigned char ch );
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,  
                                        const char* s );
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,Traits>& os,
                                        const signed char* s );
template< class Traits >
basic_ostream<char,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<char,traits>& os,
                                        const unsigned char* s );
```

---

**Why I Care To Know**:

I find the overloads at best redundant, and generally cumbersome:

1. The following overloads for non-specialized template types already exist, and provide the `char` and `char*` functionality:

   ```
   template< class CharT, class Traits>
   basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                            CharT ch );
   template< class CharT, class Traits>
   basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                            char ch );
   template< class CharT, class Traits >
   basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                            const CharT* s );
   template< class CharT, class Traits >
   basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& operator<<( basic_ostream<CharT,Traits>& os,
                                            const char* s );
   ```
2. `signed char` and `unsigned char` are not character-types, ( there are no `char_traits` for them, ) and they should be usable as integer-values, ( especially in the `stdint.h` context of `int8_t`, `uint8_t`, etc. )  Yet these overloads contrast against both of those points; one has to play games to get around these annoyances such as:

   - explicitly cast `signed char` to `signed short`, `unsigned char` to `unsigned short`, and `signed char*` or `unsigned char*` to `void*` for each use-case.

     - which requires workaround function-overloading or template partial-specializations in user code.
   - using the `wchar_t` equivalent `basic_ostream` to avoid these undesired function-overloads.

     - which likely reduces performance of user code.

   In both cases, the user code looks uglier than it need be.

Comment: @LokiAstari It has the same representation as one of them but it is a distinct type.

Comment: Just *what* about IOStreams is *not* cumbersome?

Comment: I think your real issue is not that the overloads exist, but rather that they behave as if you are passing character data, rather than integers.  Isn't that the problem?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, yes, that is the behavioural problem.  :-)  If these specific overloads didn't exist, I believe `basic_ostream` would behave closer to my expectations, and treat `signed char` and `unsigned char` as integer-types.    But there must have been some reason at the time the library was created to add the specific overloaded-functions.

Answer (score 1):

The overloads are necessary to allow the operator to be used without specifying all the template types.  If the types match, the compiler just uses the right overload.  If they don't match, it either has to do implicit conversions (undesirable) or you have to specify all the template types explicitly, and I'm not even sure there is syntax that would allow you to do so.

Comment: In my workaround example, we already have to explicitly cast individual values to `signed short` or `unsigned short`, and pointers to `void*`; these argument-types are explicitly provided as member-function overloads.  
I guess the alternative would have to include member-function overloads for `signed char` and `unsigned char`, for all `basic_stream`s.

Answer (score 1):

The char traits and the various char overloads are not related.

The char traits are about the char type and handling of the *output stream*, whereas the char overloads have to do with the char types *inserted*. Think of `basic_ostream<wchar_t>` vs. `operator<<(basic_ostream, char)` for example.

You must also consider that it is implementation defined, whether a plain char is `signed` or `unsigned`. Also

> **3.9.1 Fundamental types [basic.fundamental]**
>   1 ... Plain char, signed char, and unsigned char are three distinct types.

So, an overload for just `char` or `const char*` doesn't cover all possibilities. I guess, defining these overloads is just to be complete and for covering all fundamental types.

Comment: I understand `basic_ostream`'s second template-type is for the formatting of the `basic_ostream` itself, not with `operator<<` input-arguments. `char`, `signed char`, and `unsigned char` are three distinct C and C++ types; ( yes, the representation of `char` is the same as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, but that's unrelated to my point. )  The point is that `char` and `wchar_t` are the only character-types, ( in the C++03 standard: ) `char_traits`, `basic_string`, and `basic_ios` are only meaningful for these types; c-string literals can only be created for `char` or `wchar_t` types.

Comment: My point is that a `signed char` and `unsigned char` type should be treated as any other integer ( and non-charcter ) type.  Currently, `signed char integer = 33; std::cout << integer` will print out `!`, not `33` as expected.